# Nomenclature about prior, posterior, likelihood. What do you call the distribution of the ... "data"?

Tags: random-variables, terminology

I've been studying prior and posterior probability stuff.  Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be iid random variables indexed by some parameter $\theta$ which is unknown with prior distribution $\xi(\theta)$.  I know that $f(\vec{x}|\theta)$ is the likelihood function and $f(\theta|\vec{x})$ is the posterior distribution.  However, I haven't found any nomenclature for the variables $X_i$ or the values $x_i$.  I very often find that I want to talk about these, either in the solutions to problems or just when discussing things or writing notes on the material.  I've so far just been referring to both of these as "data" somewhat ambiguously, but it would be nice to know if there is some other more standard and distinguished way to refer to these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "data" is fine. Some people use "evidence" as well (see for example this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)). I checked [Gelman's book "Bayesian Data Analysis"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/) and he uses terms like "observations" or "observed data."

Comment: Ok, then maybe a nearly standard terminology might be to call the r.v.s "observables" and the values "observations".